# Trigger Not Inserting Child Records

Tags: trigger

I have an object `contact_relationship__c` which has a lookup relationship with `Contact`. The scenario is, there is a field in contact `contact_relationship__c`  type of `checkbox`, whenever a `Contact` record is created, the fields of `contact_relationship__c` get updated automatically.

Here is my code:

```
trigger contactrelation on Contact (after insert)
{          
    set<id>coid=new set<id>();
    for(contact con:Trigger.new)
    {
        coid.add(con.id);
    }
    Map<id,Contact_Relationship__c> mymap = new map<id,Contact_Relationship__c>([select id,name from Contact_Relationship__c where id in:coid]);
    List<Contact_Relationship__c>crl=new List<Contact_Relationship__c>();
    for(contact con:trigger.new)
    {        
        if(mymap.containskey(con.id) && con.Contact_Relationship__c==true)
        {       
            crl.add(new Contact_Relationship__c(Name__c=con.Lastname));
            insert crl;                   
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are querying `Contact_Relationship__c`  with **`Contact` Ids**.

```
Map<id,Contact_Relationship__c> mymap=
new map<id,Contact_Relationship__c>(
    [select id,name from Contact_Relationship__c where id in:coid]
);
```

- `coid` is collection of `Contact` Ids and you are querying it in `Contact_Relationship__c`
- When you do `mymap.containskey(con.id)`, since `myMap` doesn't contain any result it never enters the `if`:

  ```
   if(mymap.containskey(con.id) && con.Contact_Relationship__c==true)
  ```

**Update:**

Try this:

```
 Map<id,Contact_Relationship__c> mymap=
 new map<id,Contact_Relationship__c>(
 [select ContactId,name from Contact_Relationship__c where ContactId IN :coid]);
```